# Issue with more than 5 subgrids or 5 quick views on the form

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on crm 2013. I have more than 5 subgrids on the Form which also includes Quick view. 5th one is Quick view which also have subgrid. So if the subgrid has no records then it displays a link for me asking to "Click here to view the records". I need to get ride of this message. If there are no records it has to display no records. I tried to refresh the grid but I'm not able to do that. I am not even able to capture the Section of the Quick in java script. 
Please suggest me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward solution is to force the 5th grid to load.  I don't see any 2013 articles on the subject but here are two similar 2011 articles:

http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/12/crm-2011excessive-sub-gridding.html
http://pabdulin.blogspot.com/2013/08/microsoft-crm-2011-automatically-load.html